# SharePoint permissions not getting defined according to SharePoint groups

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, project-server

I have done migration from Project Server 2013 to Project Server 2016. All sites got created. Projects, tasks, users created finely.
The issue is no other user is able to access. I find that there is no permission given to any user although they are put in one or more SharePoint groups same as the previous environment, where it was OK.
I don't understand why SharePoint permissions are not defined according to SharePoint group.

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved that time. I had to change the permission mode to resolve this.

Comment: Please add more details in answer. what steps you followed to get this resolved.